# How to check which thread is waiting every minute in dump analysis using windbg

Tags: multithreading, windbg, dump

I have taken dump of my running application using Task Manager and opened the dump in windbg.
I know that in my C# application one of the threads is polling for some task for 1 min. if it doesn't get it, it waits for 10ms and then again starts polling for 1 min.
I see so many threads in my dump file:

```
 ~
#  0  Id: 2208.1aa8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000098`eecc4000 Unfrozen
   1  Id: 2208.5cc Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000098`eeccc000 Unfrozen
   2  Id: 2208.c38 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000098`eecce000 Unfrozen
   3  Id: 2208.2810 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000098`eecda000 Unfrozen
   4  Id: 2208.10e0 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000098`eecdc000 Unfrozen
.  5  Id: 2208.2d28 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000098`eecde000 Unfrozen
   6  Id: 2208.161c Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000098`eece0000 Unfrozen
   7  Id: 2208.15e4 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000098`eece2000 Unfrozen
   8  Id: 2208.27a4 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000098`eece8000 Unfrozen
   9  Id: 2208.2308 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000098`eecec000 Unfrozen
  10  Id: 2208.d08 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000098`eecf2000 Unfrozen
  11  Id: 2208.2f7c Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000098`eecf4000 Unfrozen
  12  Id: 2208.1338 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000098`eecfc000 Unfrozen
```

Now, how can i check which particular thread is the one that is doing the polling task.
I tried seeing stack trace of the threads but couldn't make any sense out of it.

For instance, thread 0 has the following stack trace :

```
  0  Id: 2208.1aa8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000098`eecc4000 Unfrozen
      Start: IDBrigade+0x4bf0e (0000019d`b17bbf0e) 
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32  Affinity: f
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000098`eeefe8a8 00007ffb`13e88933 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x14
00000098`eeefe8b0 00007ffb`153415bf KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x93
00000098`eeefe950 00007ffb`15340ea0 sechost!ScSendResponseReceiveControls+0x13b
00000098`eeefea90 00007ffb`153419e0 sechost!ScDispatcherLoop+0x140
00000098`eeefebd0 00007ffb`02cfbf47 sechost!StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW+0x70
00000098`eeefec00 00007ffb`02cfeea6 System_ServiceProcess_ni+0x2bf47
00000098`eeefecb0 00007ffa`a75004fb System_ServiceProcess_ni+0x2eea6
00000098`eeefed20 00007ffb`06ae6813 0x7ffa`a75004fb
00000098`eeefed70 00007ffb`06ae66c8 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
00000098`eeefedb0 00007ffb`06ae6d9d clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4e
00000098`eeefedf0 00007ffb`06b4d16c clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0xf8
00000098`eeefeef0 00007ffb`06b4d356 clr!RunMain+0x1e7
00000098`eeeff0d0 00007ffb`06b4d24b clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0xb6
00000098`eeeff3c0 00007ffb`06b4d044 clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x57c
00000098`eeeff9d0 00007ffb`06b4cfc2 clr!ExecuteEXE+0x3f
00000098`eeeffa40 00007ffb`06b4d3f4 clr!_CorExeMainInternal+0xb2
00000098`eeeffad0 00007ffb`07947cbd clr!CorExeMain+0x14
00000098`eeeffb10 00007ffb`0821a57c mscoreei!CorExeMain+0x112
00000098`eeeffb70 00007ffb`14e47974 mscoree!CorExeMain_Exported+0x6c
00000098`eeeffba0 00007ffb`17a1a271 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
00000098`eeeffbd0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

I am not able to make any sense out of it..Can anyone please help ?  This is the first time I am doing this thread dump analysis..

Comment: You need a sequence of dumps taken with a small intervals, and then `!runaway` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/tracking-down-a-processor-hog

Comment: This is a CLR process. As such, some of the stack frames will not have useful function names. You can start by loading SOS and then using !sos.dumpstack. Alternatively, if you need both native and managed threads you can download SOSEX and use !sosex.mk. You should be able to identify your thread by the method calls in the callstack.

Comment: Start looking at .NET threads (`!threads` of the SOS extension) instead of native threads

Comment: "again starts polling for 1 min" - you mean in an endless loop without any sleeps? Then @Dono is right. Do a `~*e !dumpstack`. "waits for 10ms" - really? How does it do that? Consider that the timer resolution is 17ms typically.